# Bitcoin miner with address to get funds

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitcoin, mining

I'm trying to make a bitcoin miner, But I don't know how to transfer the bitcoins to my wallet.

```
import hashlib


def get_sha_256_hash(input_value):
    return hashlib.sha256(input_value).hexdigest()


def block_hash_less_than_target(block_hash, given_target):
    return int(block_hash, 16) < int(given_target, 16)


# Initial block data (the transactions' merkle tree root, timestamp, client version, hash of the previous block)
blockData = \
    '01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' \
    '03ba3edfd7a7b12b27ac72c3e67768f617fc81bc3888a51323a9fb8aa4b1e5e4a29ab5f' \
    '49ffff001d1dac2b7c01010000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000' \
    '00000000000000000000000ffffffff4d04ffff001d0104455468652054696d65732030' \
    '332f4a616e2f32303039204368616e63656c6c6f72206f6e20627266e6b206f66207365' \
    '636f6e64206261696c6f757420666f722062616e6b73ffffffff0100f2052a010000004' \
    '34104678afdb0fe5548271967f1a67130b7105cd6a828e03909a67962e0ea1f61deb649' \
    'f6bc3f4cef38c4f35504e51ec112de5c384df7ba0b8d578a4c702b6bf11d5fac00000000' \
        .encode()

# Initial target - this is the easiest it will ever be to mine a Bitcoin block
target = '0x00000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF'

solution_found = False
block_data_hexadecimal_value = int(blockData, 16)
nonce = 0

while not solution_found:
    block_data_with_nonce = block_data_hexadecimal_value + nonce

    # Find double hash
    first_hash = get_sha_256_hash(hex(block_data_with_nonce).encode())
    second_hash = get_sha_256_hash(first_hash.encode())

    print('Nonce: ' + str(nonce))

    print('Block hash:')
    print(second_hash)

    print('Is the block hash less than the target?')
    solution_found = block_hash_less_than_target(second_hash, target)
    print(solution_found)

    if not solution_found:
```

I'm expecting an output where I can efficiently mine bitcoin and get a profit from it but I don't know where I can set that up.

Comment: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-bitcoin/9781491902639/ch08.html Look at example 8.4, "The Generation Transaction". There are a few other things from that chapter that your setup needs to handle too - like obviously you need to figure out which transactions you include in the block, and build a Merkle tree rather than hardcoding a root.